# Why is Prezi 3D background not working?

Tags: prezi

I have a presentation with three layers of backgrounds. The first two work fine, but it is impossible to zoom into the third. Here is the link to the Prezi:

https://prezi.com/ku3eahd5xchx/

How can I solve it?